# Django With FastCGI Cant Find Settings

Tags: python, django, fastcgi

Alright I am trying to delpoy django on my web server using fastcgi. I am nearly completed, but for some reason when I run the fastcgi script it cannot locate my settings.py.

Here is the error I get:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'skyblue.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings
```

dispatch.fcgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import sys
import os


sys.path.append('/home/skybluep/website/skyblue')
os.chdir("/home/skybluep/website/skyblue")
#sys.path.insert(0, '/home/skybluep/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')
os.environ[ 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' ] = 'skyblue.settings'

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

Answer (score 1):

After banging my head against the wall something clicked. I realized that python wasn't seeing skyblue.settings as a python module. So I added an __ init __ .py file to the skyblue directory. Django does create an __ init __.py file in skyblue/skyblue, but not in the first directory. I don't know why the fastcgi script couldn't figure this out from the PYTHONPATH, but whatever I finally have Django depolyed on my Apache shared hosting account using FCGI.

Just a note I did end up deleting the init.py file to get something else to work, but it seems after reading the skyblue.settings file initially it was still seen as a module even after I deleted the init file.